# Teclado esconde EditText

Tags: android

Tenho uma atividade com um `EditText` para inserir valores. Sempre que o teclado aparece, deixa de se ver o `editText` (o teclado esconde o `EditText`).

Tentei colocar no `Manifest` na referente atividade o seguinte comando:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Entretanto o teclado quando aparece continua a esconder o `EditText` e não consigo ver o que se escreve. O `EditText` é este:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditTextMeta1"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_plafond2"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:maxLength="4"/>
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você tentou colocar dentro de `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Rodolfo so funciona se for dentro de uma ScrollView?

Comment: acho que sim, pois com `ScrollView` tem como você ver o `EditText`

Comment: @porthfind tente remover `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` de seu manifesto e tente novamente. Testei aqui e deu certo (PS: não estou utilizando `ScrollView`)

Comment: @sicachester, funciona a primeira vez que tento escrever, se por qualquer motivo volto a pôr o cursor para voltar a escrever já não se desloca "o ecrã", isto não é normal pois não?

Comment: Não tem uma screenshot, ou o codigo do layout inteiro?

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive um problema bem parecido e consegui solucionar, se você quiser usar como referência:

[Espaço entre Edittext e teclado no android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204630/espa%C3%A7o-entre-edittext-e-teclado-no-android/204631#204631)

Experimenta usar no seu manifest 'adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden' e colocar 'android:layout_marginBottom' no edittext

Comment: Somente complementando, o marginBottom não precisa colocar.

Answer (score 0):

Tem usar desse modo

```
<ScrolView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditTextMeta1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_plafond2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLength="4"/> 
</ScrolView>
```

Comment: Não funcionou. O comportamento que quero é que quando o teclado aparece o EditText seja deslocado para cima e o q mudou com a scrollview foi que a area do "ecra" do teclado ficou vazia ainda antes de eu querer escrever no EditText..(não sei se me fiz entender)

Comment: @sicachester será que me podes ajudar, uma vez mais, nesta situação? Please!

Comment: Bom se nada funcionar, tente usar essa classe, AndroidBug5497Workaround.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529107/adjust-webview-when-keyboard-is-opened-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" />
</ScrollView>
```

Funcionou pra min!