# Espaço entre Edittext e teclado no android

Tags: android, edittext, teclado

Gostaria de saber se é possível  colocar uma margem para espaçar o teclado do edittext para não ficar tão perto assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O xml de como estou declarando o EditText:

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23px"
        android:layout_marginRight="23px"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/nome_login"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou setar na tua activity o [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) da seguinte maneira:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

ou

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

por definição, de acordo com a documentação,

> **adjustResize**: A janela principal da atividade é sempre redimensionada para criar espaço para o teclado de software na tela.
>
> **adjustPan**: A janela principal da atividade não é redimensionada para criar espaço para o teclado de software na tela. Em vez disso, desloca-se o conteúdo da janela automaticamente para que o foco atual nunca seja sobreposto pelo teclado e os usuários possam sempre ver o que digitam. Normalmente, esse comportamento é menos desejável que o redimensionamento, pois o usuário pode precisar fechar o teclado de software para acessar e interagir com as partes sobrepostas da janela.

Mas pelo contexto, acredito que no teu caso o `adjustResize` funcione, caso não funcione, seta na activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, juntamente com um `android:paddingBottom` no `EditText`, com o valor que julgar necessário e seta  também: `android:gravity="bottom"`.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado @Mathias, o `adjustResize` funcionou bem, segue como ficou todo o xml do campo caso sirva de referência para alguém:

no arquivo manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

e no xml da activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:hint="@string/nome_login"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botaoEntrar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/botao_entrar"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="abrirFicha"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```